# How to get value from onclick() Button to input jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a `color picker`, whenever i click on a colored button, the respective color name gets sent to the input automatically; if i click on white button i get in input : White and so on ...
Here is my code so far:

**HTML**

```js
function changewhite() {
    document.getElementById("color").innerHTML="White";
}
function changeblack() {
    document.getElementById("color").innerHTML="Black";
}
function changered() {
    document.getElementById("color").innerHTML="Red";
}
function changeblue() {
    document.getElementById("color").innerHTML="Blue";
}
function changeyellow() {
    document.getElementById("color").innerHTML="Yellow";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Color:</label>

<td width="314"><input name="white" type="button" id="white" onclick="changewhite()" value="" width="20px" />
<input name="black" type="button" id="black" onclick="changeblack()" value="" width="20px" />
<input name="red" type="button" id="red" onclick="changered()" value="" width="20px" />
<input name="blue" type="button" id="blue" onclick="changeblue()" value="" width="20px" />
<input name="yellow" type="button" id="yellow" onclick="changeyellow()" value="" width="20px" />
```

NB:
I would like to add that before using an input to get the color, i was using `<p id="color"> </p>`, the code was working perfectly, but don't know why with an input it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the input value use the `.value` not `.innerHtml` , You should also use the same function for all the inputs

```js
function changeColor(element) {
    document.getElementById("color").value = element.name;
}
```

```css
input#black {
  background-color: black;  
}

input#blue {
  background-color: blue;  
}

input#red {
  background-color: red;  
}

input#white {
  background-color: white;  
}

input#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;  
}
```

```html
<input name="white" type="button" id="white" onclick="changeColor(this)" value="" width="20px"  />
<input name="black" type="button" id="black" onclick="changeColor(this)" value="" width="20px" />
<input name="red" type="button" id="red" onclick="changeColor(this)" value="" width="20px" />
<input name="blue" type="button" id="blue" onclick="changeColor(this)" value="" width="20px" />
<input name="yellow" type="button" id="yellow" onclick="changeColor(this)" value="" width="20px" />
  
  
<input type="text" id="color"  />
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! Works perfectly 100%

Answer (score 0):

Hope you using jquery, if so update the html and click handler

```
<td width="314"><input name="colourChange" type="button" id="white" value="" width="20px" />
<input name="colourChange" type="button" id="black" value="" width="20px" />
<input name="colourChange" type="button" id="red"  value="" width="20px" />
<input name="colourChange" type="button" id="blue"  value="" width="20px" />
<input name="colourChange" type="button" id="yellow"  value="" width="20px" />


$("input[name='colourChange']").click(function() {
 var color = this.id;
 console.log(color);
});
```